# JList sudden change

Tags: java, swing, jlist, gridbaglayout

In the picture below, the bottom `JComponent` is a `JList` (list) within a `JScrollPane`.
By default the number of visible rows was 8 or 10, I don't know.
But suddenly, while I was making more changes to the project it changed
to this, and now I can only see one item at a time (fsgisfg).
How can I change the number of rows to be displayed at a time?

`list.setVisibleRowCount(8)` doesn't work.

The `list` uses an extension of `AbstractListModel` as a model.

The main menu `JFrame` uses `GridBagLayout`.

I don't know what could possibly make this happen because I even tried to undo
all the changes made in the project, and the result is still the same.

```
private JList<String> list;
[...]

list = new JList<String>(); 
list.setVisibleRowCount(8); //doesn't change anything
[...]

JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(list);
[...]

list.setModel(new BookListModel(library));
list.repaint(); //the model gets the data for the list, and refresh is needed

[...]

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 4;
c.gridwidth = 2;
frame.add(scroll2, c);
```

[image http://dl.dropbox.com/u/71389667/problem.jpg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/71389667/problem.jpg)

Comment: you should add some of your code...

Comment: This isn't enough for use to deduce what's going on.  You really need to provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The idea is that I don't know either what caused this because at first it was no problem . I cannot show all the code, because I don't know where's the problem :(.

Comment: Are you using version control of any kind? Are you able to revert your code back to the latest version that was working? For large projects, this is a great tool to have available.

Comment: No, I dont't. But while I was undoing all the changes I thought that this would be great :))

Comment: I SHOULD ADD THAT THE SCROLL ON THE RIGHT IS WORKING, AND I CAN SEE THE OTHER BOOKS' NAME. SO I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HOW IT'S DISPLAYED THAT JLIST OR JSCROLLPANE

Comment: Are you using a gui builder (like netbeans' one)? If that's the case, the visibleRowCount may be modified on the generated code...

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and all the code is hand written.

Comment: What about this empty space above and below components, whats there?

Comment: *"I cannot show all the code, because I don't know where's the problem"*  The process of making an SSCCE often shows the source of the problem!  I vote for the advice of @MadProgrammer.

Comment: How you know the number of elements is really more than 1? There need more code to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emm... it is quite hard now to get what causes the problem so first I do advise you to read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) before you keep looking the bug...

As for this moment, I just may assume that the problem is actually may come from Layout Managers or something in this direction... Try to play around the JList containing panel (or what component you using...) layout manager. It seems like right now you are using some kind of **absolute one** so change it to lets say FlowLayout for example.

As another tip, check was the ListModel added null element(s)?

For more suggestions, there would be good to see more code...

---

Report if it helped

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem, but I don't know what's causing it:     First of all, my books are saved in xml files in a folder on disk ( called Library ); now if I delete this folder, so that the button Create Library is enabled, the JList appears to be of normal size (with 8 rows being displayed). Even if I add books, JList remains the same, which is good. The problem appears when I try to actually change the xml file that has been created, because by default the file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book name="name" author="author" isbn="isbn" />`
```

If I make it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book name="name" author="" author="" >
<chapter title="chapter1">
    <paragraph>
        <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
        <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
        <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
        <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
    </paragraph>

</chapter>
</book>
```

the JList display screws up.

If I make it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book name="fadsf" author="" isbn="" >
    <chapter title="chapter1">
         <paragraph>
            <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
            <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
            <sentence>sentence1</sentence>
    </paragraph>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

it works fine. 
If I add a fourth sentence tag things get ugly.

Comment: I dont know why, but it seemed to work by making the frame bigger and setting the minimum rows for list 
  list.setVisibleRowCount(8);
  frame.setSize(400, 500);

Comment: Do you use BorderLayout? I am not sure the image you show in the question contain a wide panel in the 'NORTH', am I right? So try to set FlowLayout to the north panel or correct me if I mistaken the layout manager because the image is not pretty clear :S

Comment: I'm using GridBagLayout, and as you can see in the picture I resized the window on purpose to show that it wasn't changing. Anyway no it seems to work as I want, so sonsider the problem solved :).

Comment: Actually this shouldn't basically depend on JFrame static scale it should work even if you use pack() method :S So the problem is supposed to be a little more deeper... So I can recommend not to use layout manager as GridBagConstraints directly in JFrame but use it as an additional one; Try to make GridLayout as a base one...